# UPDATE Query with Equijoin

Tags: mysql, sql, database, jdbc

I have two tables.

**Student** *(which has following columns)*

| StudentID | StudentName | FeeAccount | Class |

```
   01       Kid1          01      One     

   02       Kid2          02      Three
```

#### FeeAccount is foreign key from table FeeAccounts.

And I have table, **FeeAccounts** *(which has following Columns)*

| FeeAccount | StudentID | MonthlyFee | Arrears |

```
    01       01          --       --
    02       02          --       --
```

#### StudentID is foreign key from table Students.

====================**PROBLEM**========================

I want to update values for *MonthlyFee* column in FeeAccounts table, but a specific fee for each student's class must be added. For example, for class One, I want to add 500 to *monthlyfee* and I want to add 700 to student's account who is in class Three.

> IN OTHER WORDS
>   *I want to update monthlyfees based on Student's Class where Student's class should be obtained using foreign key, i.e. StudentID.*

I can `SELECT` my required columns, but I don't seem to understand how to `UPDATE` it, using ***Equijoin***.

SELECT Query would be like this:

```
SELECT f.feeaccount, f.studentname, s.class
FROM feeaccounts f, student s
WHERE f.studentid = s.studentid;
```

*[[Btw I'm going to use the query in JDBC, so I hope your help will be JDBC compatible ]]*

Comment: There is no monthlyfee in your SELECT. Add it showing what value it should be based on other tables. You want to update it to *what* "based on" and "using"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) explains that there is a multi-table UPDATE. It gives an example of updating one table by mentioning another. (RTM.)

```
UPDATE FeeAccount f, Student s
SET f.MonthlyFee = foo(...,f.Arrears,...,s.Class,...)
WHERE f.StudentId = s.StudentId;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is normal update on FeeAccounts table i believe,

```
UPDATE FeeAccounts set MonthlyFee = MonthlyFee + 500 where FeeAccount = 01; //For Class One
UPDATE FeeAccounts set MonthlyFee = MonthlyFee + 700 where FeeAccount = 03; //For Class Three
```

You need to update each Class MonthlyFee depending on FeeAccount value.
Is this what you need, isn't?

Comment: **NO Absolutely** I want to update monthlyfees based on Student's Class where Student's class should be obtained using *foreign key*, i.e. StudentID.